# How do I map a list of Templates with Glass Mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper

I've got a `TreeList` field on one of my templates that allows me to select multiple templates. I'm having trouble mapping this to my model with Glass Mapper.

```csharp
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{Template-Id-Here}")]
public class MyModel
{
    private const string FieldId = "{Field-Id-Here}";

    [SitecoreField(Id = FieldId]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(Id = FieldId)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TemplateItem> TemplateItems { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(Id = FieldId)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

With the above model, the `Items` property always gets populated with the selected templates from my field, but the `Templates` and `TemplateItems` properties throw exceptions when accessed.

I've tried this with `TreeListEx` and `Multilist` fields with the same results. Can Glass Mapper not map `Template` or `TemplateItem`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Glass Mapper can't map `Template` or `TemplateItem` out of the box. However, it's easy to create field mappers so that it can.

### Field Mappers

To map `Template`, create the following field mapper:

```csharp
public class SitecoreFieldTemplateMapper : AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper
{
    public SitecoreFieldTemplateMapper()
        : base(typeof(Template))
    {
    }

    public override object GetFieldValue(
        string fieldValue, 
        SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        if (!ID.TryParse(fieldValue, out var templateId)) return null;

        var templateEngine = context.Service.Database.Engines.TemplateEngine;
        var template = templateEngine.GetTemplate(templateId);
        return template;
    }

    public override string SetFieldValue(
        object value, 
        SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, 
        SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        if (value == null) null;

        var template = value as Template;
        if (template == null)
            throw new MapperException($"The value is not of type {typeof(Template)}");

        return template.ID.ToString();
    }
}
```

To map `TemplateItem`, create the following mapper:

```csharp
public class SitecoreFieldTemplateItemMapper : AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper
{
    public SitecoreFieldTemplateItemMapper()
        : base(typeof(TemplateItem))
    {
    }

    public override object GetFieldValue(
        string fieldValue,
        SitecoreFieldConfiguration config,
        SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        if (!ID.TryParse(fieldValue, out var templateId)) return null;

        var item = context.Service.Database.GetItem(templateId);
        if (item?.TemplateID != Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Template) return null;

        return new TemplateItem(item);
    }

    public override string SetFieldValue(
        object value, 
        SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, 
        SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        var templateItem = value as TemplateItem;
        if (templateItem == null)
            throw new MapperException($"The value is not of type {typeof(TemplateItem)}");

        return templateItem.ID.ToString();
    }
}
```

In both cases, you pass the type (e.g., `typeof(Template)`) to the base constructor to instruct Glass Mapper which property types it should use the field mapper for (e.g., `Template`, `IEnumerable<Template>`). The `GetFieldValue` method tells Glass Mapper how to read from Sitecore to your property; the `SetFieldValue` method tells Glass Mapper how to write from your property back to Sitecore.

You don't need to write separate mappers for `IEnumerable<Template>` or `IEnumerable<TemplateItem>` because [the built-in `SitecoreFieldIEnumerableMapper` will handle that for you](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/DataMappers/SitecoreFieldIEnumerableMapper.cs).

### Add to Glass Mapper

Glass Mapper 5 offers a slightly cleaner way to register custom mappers than 4 through pipeline processors. Although the method for Glass Mapper 4 technically works with 5, I recommend the processor approach for flexibility and future-proofing.

Notice that in both versions the mappers are added to the `DataMapperFactory` with `First` and not `Add`. This is important--if the custom mappers are added [after the `SitecoreFieldIEnumerableMapper` in the `DataMapperFactory`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/860924dfef747a50ccd16ce8f4fb4969ac86f6c6/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/IoC/DataMapperConfigFactory.cs#L33), the custom mappers will never get invoked.

#### Glass Mapper 5

For Glass Mapper 5, create the following pipeline processor to wire up the field mappers:

```csharp
public class AddTemplateMappers : CreateResolverProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CreateResolverPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var dependencyResolver = args.DependencyResolver;
        dependencyResolver.DataMapperFactory.First(
            () => new SitecoreFieldTemplateMapper());
        dependencyResolver.DataMapperFactory.First(
            () => new SitecoreFieldTemplateItemMapper());
    }
}
```

and add it to the `glassMapper.createResolver` pipeline:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <glassMapper.createResolver>
        <processor type="YourAssembly.AddTemplateMappers, YourAssembly" />
      </glassMapper.createResolver>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

#### Glass Mapper 4

For Glass Mapper 4, modify the `GlassMapperScCustom` in your solution as follows:

```csharp
public static class GlassMapperScCustom
{
    public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver()
    {
        var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();

        var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);
        dependencyResolver.DataMapperFactory.First(
            () => new SitecoreFieldTemplateMapper());
        dependencyResolver.DataMapperFactory.First(
            () => new SitecoreFieldTemplateItemMapper());
        return dependencyResolver;
    }

    // other methods omitted for brevity
}
```